# SSIS - Only Load Certain Records - Skip the remaining

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a Flat File that I'm loading into SQL and that Flat file has 2 different RecordTypes and 2 Different File Layouts based on the RecordType.
So I may have

```
000010203201501011 (RecordType 1)
00002XXYYABCDEFGH2 (RecordType 2)
```

So I want to immediately check for Records of RecordType1 and then send those records thru [Derived Column] & [Data Conversion] & [Loading to SQL]

And I want to ignore all Records of RecordType2.

I tried a Conditional Split but it seems like the Records of RecordType2 are still trying to go thru the [Derived Column]&[DataConversion] Steps.

It gives me a DataConversion error on the RecordType2 Records.

I have the Conditional Split set up as RecordType == 1 to go thru the process i have set up.

I guess Conditional Split isn't set up to be used this way?
Where in my process can i tell it to check for RecordType1 and only send records past that point that are RecordType=1?

Comment: This doesn't seem like something that should be difficult to do?  I don't know why i cant find more about this online?

Comment: SSIS does not play nicely with mixed record format files. Mainframes love 'em, SSIS hates 'em.

Comment: That said, you haven't provided enough information to solve your problem. If your Ragged Right Flat File Connection manager was defined with 2 columns, `RecordType` which is DT_STR of length 5 and `TheRest` which is everything beyond the first 5 characters. If your Conditional Split is testing for `00001` then the only thing that could be going down that route is the 1 records

Comment: My Flat File is defined by 530 Column Names. - Up until 2015 all the records were RecordType1.  Now they're including RecordType2's in the same file.  RecordType 2 is only 190 Columns (with a Filler at the end to make it the same length as the RecordType1's.

Comment: One thing i found is I need to set "ignore" to all Truncation and Errors in the Flat File Source Editor at the Beginning.  Now that I have set all to "Ignore Failure" I can get to the Conditional Split.  In the Conditional Split i have the one Expression for RecordType==1.  Then I have the Default Condition just going to a RowCount.  It seems like i'm getting close now.

Comment: So RecordType2 records **Were Not** going thru the [Derived Column]&[DataConversion] Steps (Like i said in my original post).  _They were erroring out before they even got to the Conditional Split._

Comment: SSIS is keen on keeping consistent metadata. The RecordType2 is inconsistent with Type1 unless every column is defined with the same length and data type in both. Which it's not. So you have inconsistent metadata. So you need CountOfRecordTypes+1 Connection Managers Defined. The first Connection Manager views your data as however many characters required to find the key to split the data out by. The second column is variable length and is everything else. You then get to  write that all to dedicated files instead of this mixed record type.

Comment: The other approach is an unholy abomination of read the whole row, conditional split and then two sets of the most painful and unmaintainable Derived Column transformations where you manually parse that big string into 530 columns or 190

Comment: Use your favorite search engine. We've been dealing with this since 2005 and it's not a good story. You either have to double process the source file or you have to throw out all the native parsing and validation by writing your own validation in the data flow itself.

Comment: do you want to pass only record type 1...?

Comment: There is a walk-around to get rejected rows when you enable the "Ignore" truncation errors, however, the problem is that you could potentially be ignoring valid errors from RecordType 1 too! And you want to keep the future errors for this type.

Answer (score 0):

It makes perfect sense you are having data type errors for Record Type 2 rows since you probably have defined columns along with their data types based on Record Type 1 records. I see three options to achieve what you want to do:

1. Have a script task in the control flow to copy only Record Type 1
   records to a fresh file that would be used by the data flow you
   already have (Pro: you do not need to touch the data flow, Con:
   reading file twice), OR
2. In the existing data flow: Instead of getting all the columns from
   the data source, read every line coming from the file as one big-fat
   column, then a Derived Column to get RecordType, then a Conditional
   Split, then a Derived Column to re-create all the columns you had
   defined in the data source, OR
3. Ideal if you have another package processing Record Type 2 rows:
   Dump the file into a database table in the staging area, then
   replace the Data Source in your Data Flow for an OLEDB Data Source
   (or whatever you use) and obtain+filter the records with something
   like: `SELECT substring(rowdata,1,5) AS RecordType,
   substring(rowdata,6,...) AS Column2, .... FROM STG.FileData WHERE
   substring(rowdata,1,5) = '00001'`. If using this approach it would
   be better to have a dedicated column for RecordType